# Reducing 301 htaccess redirects with https,non-www and sub folder

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect following:

1. Redirect all request to SSL
2. Redirect www to non-www
3. Redirect request for root domain to /sub-directory/ but not redirecting if existing directory is present. (still keeping rule 1 and rule 2 )
4. Redirecting old urls example.com/REQUEST to example.com/sub-directory/REQUEST

I have been able to do all, only problem is that I can never get myself well acquainted with mod_redirect rules hence can't make it efficient. Have gone through almost all related questions here and still little confused and ofcourse want to remove redundancy...

So here is code I have in .httaccess

```
# Remove www + force https on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]


#Add Sub-directory for fixing old urls when site  was in root 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-directory/
#Only apply rules for above condition if requested file or directory doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-directory/$1 [NC,R=301]

# If reqeust is made to only domain root then redirect to domain.com/sub-directory/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /sub-directory/ [L,R=301]
```

Now above is able to redirect  all 1, 2, 3, 4 conditions as I outlined above in beginning

But there are multiple request. 
eg: For condition 3rd, its first redirecting to http://example.com --> https://example.com ---> http://example.com/sub-directory/

I know, is not big deal, can live with it, but still , can it be like something:

```
# Remove www + force https on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/sub-directory%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

But then above also redirect everything to sub-directory so not useful. Any advice, how to make it efficient and to the point ie. achieving all in conditions internally in 1 redirect only ?

Comment: do you have only one domain or more ? i meant are there another domains ,or sub-domains ?

Comment: Its only for single domain, no subdomain thing, as mentioned, you can assume it example.com